# Gson fromJson parsing a list sometimes returning null

Tags: android, json

I have an application communicating to a server through Json data. Sometimes the server answers back with a list of objects and the application parses the json string using the syntax :

```
List<My_Object_Type> list = new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<My_Object_Type>>() {}.getType());
```

Through my application log, i *always* print what the server answer in order to be able to check if everything is correct and diagnosis errors. Thus i'm able to see if the gson syntax is correct, if the server encountered a problem or...

The application works fine, almost 99% of the time, but in the little 1% remaining the json List is null. And that's not even a problem about the data structure, neither the json String because in the same application log i saw the ***exact*** same json line in the exact same query being answered, and there was no problem.
Question : if the gson deserialization is called on another Thread (asynTask), could it lead to it to fail deserializing ? I dont see any reason why the first call works, the second one too, but not the third one.

In order to further get any problem, I copy/past the Json string and directly called the deserialization through the exact same call (also copy/pasted)... And it worked.

- Worked first --> no data structure error
- Worked with copy/pasted string --> No string error

what could be other problems with deserialization ?

PS: I read other questions leading to "wrong json string" or "wrong object structure" and it seems not being the case as it worked with the exact same string before.... Of course, I could deal with the null variable and prevent problems, but as it does not take data sent by the server it may lead to inappropriate behaviors....

**Edit** : The main issue is that the variable "list" is null. The Json string isn't null at all : i checked it in the log [it is not my first iteration to found the bug]. It is a full list of My_Object_Type, and the exact same json string (I compared to previous server request) was deserialized correctly just before. That's why i'm so surprised.

In order to be more clear : the json string come from "json_encode" function in php, applied to the PDO request result to get a database table content. Each line of the table is one of my object. The Json string is not null at all, and was deserialized correctly just before, but SOMETIMES [why ? this is the question] it is not deserialized properly and i get a null variable as list answer.

Comment: Can you share a sample JSON for the case you are getting a null object?

Comment: @Feuby Have you tried logging serialized json i.e. before deserializing to java object. If serialized json also contains null then the problem is in the reponse not while deserialization

Comment: @Doron i can't show you the json object. Basically it's really long because it is generated from a database table content using "json_encode" on the PDO request result. Therefore i highly doubt there is any problem for that. Saqib ->what do you mean by "logging serialized json before deserializing" ? do deserializing modify the string ? because if not, the log contains exactly the server answer, and the json string is not null at all. I edited the question for some more precisions